# Can't modify the contents of specific columns with binary values

Tags: r, data.table

I have 10 columns in the `data.table` DataDia.

```
> head(DataDia[,c(7:16)])
    Type soin 01  Type soin 02 Type soin 03 Type soin 04 Type soin 05 Type soin 06 Type soin 07          Type soin 08              Type soin 09 Type soin 10
1: crme de jour                                   sérum                                        démaquillant à rincer                                       
2:                                                             masque                           démaquillant à rincer                                       
3:               crme de nuit                     sérum                    lotion                                                                          
4:                                                 sérum                    lotion  eau florale                                                             
5: crme de jour                                   sérum                                                              démaquillant sans rinage             
6:               crme de nuit        huile        sérum
```

I just want to apply a general function that **modify** the contains **just only** for these columns to binary values. If the columns have empty cells then it will be replaced by 0 else by 1.
 So I write these code:

```
DataDia[,DataDia[,c(5:10)]:=lapply(colnames(DataDia[,c(5:10)]), function(x) {if (DataDia[,x]==""){0} else {1}})]
```

But I get this error:

> Error in `[.data.table`(DataDia, , `:=`(DataDia[, c(7:16)],
>   lapply(colnames(DataDia[,  :  LHS of := must be a symbol, or an atomic
>   vector (column names or positions).

Note that I want to work with `data.table` operations. But I don't know why this doesn't work here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `:=`?  Surely not R (Use `<-`). Also, I don't understand why `DataDia[,DataDia[,c(5:10)]`. There is a `]` missing and from what I have seen, `DataDia[, 5:10]` will do just fine.

Comment: Try `lapply(DataDia[, 5:10], function(x) as.integer(x == ""))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, I need to replace the columns so that I use `:=`. In fact I want not each time to add other columns and delete the origin ones. Also I think you for your suggestion but it doesn't work!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(DataDia[, 5:10])`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(DataDia[1:20, 5:10])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a vocabulary point : your cells with "" are not empty cells, but cells containing an empty character string with is in itself a value. "Empty cells" refer to missing values, which appear as NA in a table.

Usually, missing data should already be identified as such when loading the data in R (e.g. by the `na.strings =` argument in the `read.table` function). If you tell me how you loaded your data, I could help you on how to do this.

As for your code, I would go for something much simpler:

`DataDia[,5:10] <- data.table(0+ !(DataDia[,5:10] == ""))`

NB: The `0 +` part is used here to obtain a numric value of 0 for `FALSE` and 1 for `TRUE`. The exclamation mark is used to test the contrary of the written condition (we want it to return `FALSE` or 0 when the cell is ""). You need the `data.table` function because matrices do not seem to coerce correctly to `data.table`.

Here is the code working on a sample dataset:

```
> DataDia
    Produit1 Produit2 Produit3 Produit4
 1:                 b        c        d
 2:        a        b        c         
 3:        a                 c        d
 4:        a        b                 d
 5:        a                 c        d
 6:        a        b        c        d
 7:                 b        c        d
 8:        a        b        c        d
 9:        a        b                 d
10:        a        b        c        d

> DataDia[,2:3] <- data.table(0+ !(DataDia[,2:3] == ""))
> DataDia
    Produit1 Produit2 Produit3 Produit4
 1:                 1        1        d
 2:        a        1        1         
 3:        a        0        1        d
 4:        a        1        0        d
 5:        a        0        1        d
 6:        a        1        1        d
 7:                 1        1        d
 8:        a        1        1        d
 9:        a        1        0        d
10:        a        1        1        d
```

Comment: thank you for your remark, first as you suggest I modify the importing of data as `DataDia=fread("Diagnostic.csv",na.strings = c("","NA"))`, then I did as you suggest  `DataDia[,7:16] <- as.numeric(!(DataDia[,7:16] %in% "NA"))` , but have **Big** warning message. In your information I have also many warning message when I import data!

Comment: If you have NAs instead of "", these are no character strings anymore, so `%in% "NA"` will not work. In this case, use `DataDia[,7:16] <- as.numeric(!is.na(DataDia[,7:16]))`.

Comment: thank you it works but I have warnings messages! _Messages d'avis :
1: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , 7:16, value = c(1, 0, 0,  ... :
  Supplied 81100 items to be assigned to 8110 items of column 'Type soin 01' (72990 unused)_

Comment: Sorry, I am more familiar with the behaviour of standard `data.frame`objects than with `data.table`objects. Here is the code I tested on a `data.table` : `DataDia[,7:16] <- data.table(0+ !is.na(DataDia[,7:16]))`